# Calculate input field based on expiry date

Tags: javascript, jquery

A form with 50 entries: each with P1-48, E1-48, and X1-48. I want to calculate the Entry Fee "E1" based on the expires date X1. The js date format for the expires date is YYYY.MM.DD, ex. 2018.04.21 and a player pays $3 if his expires date is greater or equal to today's date. He pays $5 if his expires date is older or less than today's date. But if the expires date is blank and the player pays a membership fee, the Entry Fee is waived to zero.

**JS:**

```
<script src = "js/moment.min.js"></script>
```

I also have this as a "template" starting guide. I think it could be modified and piggyback the target result onto it.

```
<script> // change expiration date color
function getExpireDate(ele) {
var i = null;
for (i = 0; members.length > i; i++) {
    if (members[i].Name == ele.value) {
        var exDate = moment(members[i].Expires, 'YYYY.MM.DD');
        if (moment().isAfter(exDate)) {
        $(ele).closest('.universal').find('.expDate').css('color', "#A3005B");
        } else {
        $(ele).closest('.universal').find('.expDate').css('color', "#275052");
        }
        return members[i].Expires;
     }
}
return '';
}
</script>

<script>

for (let i = 0; i <= 48; i++) {
    $("#P" + i).on("blur", function(){
    $("#X" +i).val(getExpireDate(this));
    });
}
</script>

<script>

    var members [
    {"Name": "Jones, David", "Expires": "2017.05.03" },
    {"Name": "Roth, Bill", "Expires": "2017.03.08" },
    {"Name": "Scullin, Kenn", "Expires": "2019.02.20" }
    ]

<script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <input type = "text" id = "P1"> <!--Player-->
    <input type = "text" id = "E1"> <!--Entry Fee--> 
    <input type = "text" id = "M1"> <!--Membership Fee--> 
<input type = "text" id = "X1" onblur="getExpireDate()" class="expDate"> <!--expires-->
<div>
```

**Funny thing is:**

```
<input type = "text" onblur="getClass()" class="text" id="Y1" maxlength = "4" size = "4" disabled /> <!--works even with input disabled -->

<input type = "text" onblur="calcEntryFee(this);" class="expDate" name = "exp" id="X1" maxlength = "10" size = "10" disabled /><!--new code doesn't work -->

<script> // Lookup class or rating

function getClass(ele) {
var i = null;
for (i = 0; members.length > i; i++) {
if (members[i].Name == ele.value) {
return members[i].Rating;

}
}
return;
}


for (let i = 0; i <= 48; i++) {
$("#P" + i).on("blur", function(){
$("#Y" +i).val(getClass(this));
});
}
</script>
```

Comment: what have you tried. ? Please come up with at least one of your tries.

Comment: good question, I'll post the reply above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

(The main `function` is `calcEntryFee()`.)

```
var members = [
  // ... fill data here.
];

function getMemberData( name ) {
    var a = jQuery.trim( name ).toLowerCase(),
        i, b, member;

    for ( i = 0; i < members.length; i++ ) {
        b = jQuery.trim( members[ i ].Name ).toLowerCase();
        if ( a === b ) {
            member = members[ i ];
            break;
        }
    }

    return member || {};
}

function calcEntryFee( elem ) {
    var idx, member, exDate, today, fee;

    elem = elem || {};
    if ( /^[PEMX](\d+)$/.test( elem.id ) ) {
        idx = RegExp.$1;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

    member = getMemberData( jQuery( '#P' + idx ).val() );
    mmfee = parseFloat( jQuery( '#M' + idx ).val() );
    exDate = moment( member.Expires, 'YYYY.MM.DD' );
    today = moment();
    fee = '';

    if ( exDate.isBefore( today ) ) {
        fee = 5;
    } else if ( exDate.isSameOrAfter( today ) ) {
        fee = 3;
    } else if ( ! member.Expires && mmfee > 0 ) {
        fee = 0;
    }

    // Updates the entry fee input value.
    jQuery( '#E' + idx ).val( fee );

    return fee;
}
```

You'd use `calcEntryFee()` like this:

```
<input id="X1" placeholder="X" size="10" onblur="calcEntryFee( this );" />
```

See the full code and **try a live demo on https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WJRNVY**.

**UPDATE**

Because the expiry date field/`input` is *disabled*, use this instead: (take note of the `id` value, which could also be `P2`, `P3`, etc.)

```
<input id="P1" placeholder="P" onblur="calcEntryFee( this );" />
```

I.e. Add the `calcEntryFee( this );` to the `onblur` attribute of the "Player" field and *not the expiry date field*. Or add it to any sibling/related fields which is *not disabled*, or which we **can tab to**. (So that we can focus and "un-focus" or blur on the field, and the browser would then invoke the `calcEntryFee( this );` that was attached to the field's `blur` event.)

Try a live demo on: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xjgQyx

**Alternatively**, you may add it *without using the* `onblur` attribute of the `input`/field: (refer to the code you provided in your question)

```
for (let i = 0; i <= 48; i++) {
  $("#P" + i).on("blur", function() {
    $("#X" + i).val(getExpireDate(this));
    calcEntryFee(this); // <- add it here
  });
}
```

Comment: Why does your demo work so well, and my implementation at http://communitychessclub.com/sally.php not work? AFAIK they are identical?

Comment: Because you forgot to load the Moment JS library. In that [Pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WJRNVY), under the "Settings" menu, then in the "JavaScript" tab, you'd see *https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.js* in the "external scripts" section.

Comment: And if you want the dummy fields, you'd also need to copy the JS code under the "Demo stuff." in the Pen. Or you could just manually enter a *valid* date in the 'X' field, and a *valid* player name in the 'P' field, in your demo page.

Comment: Trouble is that the input ID for Expiry Date is disabled, so it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. But when I visited the demo (on your site), the Moment JS library wasn't loaded on the page. The `input` was not disabled..

Comment: Sally, I added some sample code above at end to show that similar code getClass works even when input is disabled, but your code doesn't. Other that your code is fine. I hope you can fix this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170022/discussion-between-sally-cj-and-verlager).

Comment: I know we've discussed it, but I updated the answer, because I think it could help others as well. =)

Answer (score 2):

Had to re-read your question a few times. I'm still not sure a fully understand what you're trying to achieve, but I believe this is pretty close:

```
let getMember = {
  index: function(name) {
    let index = -1;
      $.each(members, function(i, player) {
      if (player.Name === name) { index = i; }
    });
    return index;
  },
  entryFee: function(memberIndex) {
    if (memberIndex === -1) {
      return 'waived';
    } else {}
      let today = new Date();
      let expires = new Date(members[memberIndex].Expires.replace(/\./g, '-'));
      return today <= expires ? '$3' : '$5';    
    }
};

let members = [
  {"Name": "Jones, David", "Expires": "2017.05.03" },
  {"Name": "Roth, Bill", "Expires": "2017.03.08" },
  {"Name": "Scullin, Kenn", "Expires": "2019.02.20" }
];


let tableHTML = '';

for (let i=0; i < 50; i++) {
    tableHTML += `
  <div class="row">
    <input type="text" class="player" placeholder="player">
    <input type="text" class="entryFee" placeholder="entry fee">
    <input type="text" class="membershipFee" placeholder="membership fee">
    <input type="text" class="expDate" placeholder="expire date">
  <div>`;
}

$(`<div class="table">${tableHTML}</div>`)
  .appendTo('body')
  .on('blur', '.player', function() {
    if (!this.value) { return false; }
    let memberIndex = getMember.index(this.value);
    let entryFee = getMember.entryFee(memberIndex);

    $(this)
      .next().val(entryFee)
      .next().val(entryFee === 'waived' ? 'yes' : 'no')
      .next()
        .val(memberIndex >= 0 ? members[memberIndex].Expires : 'non-member')
        .addClass(entryFee === '$3' ? 'currentMember' : 'nonCurrentMember');

    $('.player').eq($('.player').index(this) + 1).focus();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ypzjfkxk/

Without an external library to boot! Can't say I have any experience with moment.js, but all of the questions I've come across seem to be solvable in plain javascript. Also, it would be just as fast and easy to generate an alphabetical table for this. Then you wouldn't have to worry about typos in the player input. Unless you're trying to create a log or something?

Comment: Much of the code you wrote I have to undo. LIke ... the membership expiration date should show the date. Membership fee is not "no". It's a number or blank. Take a look at http://verlager.com/account-pure.php click the folder and click "ok" and hold the the {tab} key down. See how the numbers fill in automatically? We want that for EF Entry fee! Here's the problem: the solution has to be simple, not complex. Or we get painted into a corner from which we can never get out.

Comment: LIne 154 of http://verlager.com/account-pure.php is the basis for the row by row player listing. We want a function that fills in the EF entry fee to spec.

Comment: The first time I attempted the link you provide, it required login credentials. Now it redirects me to install chrome. I do not have access to your supplemental code.

Comment: OK I have fixed the login browser nag and removed requiring credentials.

Comment: The member expiration date does show the expiration date or says "non-member" if the input doesn't match a players name exactly. It also changes color based on whether it's current or not since you had that in your original code. You never state how much the membership fee is, so I just assumed it was yes or no based on whether it was owed. Following your direction fills out the first input and then cycles through the proceeding inputs. No numbers fill anywhere. I think my getMember.entryFee() function is as simple as you can get for what you're asking...`return today <= expires ? '$3' : '$5'`

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.js"></script>



    <script type="application/javascript">
      var members = [
        {"Name": "Jones, David", "Expires": "2017.05.03" },
        {"Name": "Scullin, Kenn", "Expires": "2019.02.20" },
        {"Name": "Peter, Kenn", "Expires": "2018.04.24" },
        {"Name": "Chris, Kennx", "Expires": "" }
      ];

      $(document).ready(function(){
        var nUsers = 4; // Number os users

        // Fill inputs (tmp: visual purpose)
        for (count=1; count<=nUsers; count++){
          $("#P"+count).val(members[count-1].Name);
          $("#X"+count).val(members[count-1].Expires);
        }
        $("#M4").val("$20");

        /* Get current date. For security purpose you should
          get this from the server and not the client side.*/
        var date = moment().toDate();

        // Go through every input row
        for (count=1; count<=nUsers; count++){
          var exDate = $("#X"+count).val(); // Get the exire date

          // Confirm that date is has the right format
          if (moment(exDate, 'YYYY.MM.DD').isValid()){
            exDate = moment(exDate, 'YYYY.MM.DD').toDate();
            var diff = new Date(exDate - date);
            var nDays = parseInt(diff/1000/60/60/24);

            console.log(nDays);

            if (nDays >= 0){ // If his expires date is greater or equal to today's date
              $("#E"+count).val("$3");
              $("#X"+count).css('color', "#275052");
            }
            if (nDays < 0){
              $("#E"+count).val("$5"); // If his expires date is older or less than today's date
              $("#X"+count).css('color', "#A3005B");
            }
          }
          else{ // If expire date is empty
            var mFee = parseFloat($("#M"+count).val().replace(/\$/, ''));
            if ((exDate.length == 0) && (mFee > 0 )){ // If the expires date is blank and the player pays a membership fee
              $("#E"+count).val("$0");
            }
          }
        }
      });
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- visual purpose -->
    <div>
      <input type = "text" id = "P1"> <!--Player-->
      <input type = "text" id = "E1"> <!--Entry Fee-->
      <input type = "text" id = "M1"> <!--Membership Fee-->
      <input type = "text" id = "X1" class="expDate"> <!--expires-->

      <br>

      <input type = "text" id = "P2"> <!--Player-->
      <input type = "text" id = "E2"> <!--Entry Fee-->
      <input type = "text" id = "M2"> <!--Membership Fee-->
      <input type = "text" id = "X2" class="expDate"> <!--expires-->

      <br>

      <input type = "text" id = "P3"> <!--Player-->
      <input type = "text" id = "E3"> <!--Entry Fee-->
      <input type = "text" id = "M3"> <!--Membership Fee-->
      <input type = "text" id = "X3" class="expDate"> <!--expires-->

      <br>

      <input type = "text" id = "P4"> <!--Player-->
      <input type = "text" id = "E4"> <!--Entry Fee-->
      <input type = "text" id = "M4"> <!--Membership Fee-->
      <input type = "text" id = "X4" class="expDate"> <!--expires-->

    <div>

  </body>
</html>
```

And a recommendation that I gave to you in the code is you should get the current time from the server side and not from the client side.

I hope that works for you. :)

Comment: Here's why it doesn't work. http://verlager.com/account-pure.php and click folder. Click OK. Press and hold tab. The data is filled in. But not the Entry Fee which must work onblur on P1-48. We have about 5 mins. to register 40 players, hence the need for speed.

Comment: I enter a name, press tab and the numbers fill in. Repeat... enter another name, numbers fill in. Not all 48 names at once which it too slow. Just that one tuple, get it?

Comment: I had to take your code out temporarily because Wed. is chess club night. I'll put your code back Thu. I appreciate your efforts thus far.